# Prevent a single host from consuming entire bandwidth?

Tags: linux, firewall, routing, bandwidth, shorewall

We have a linux router providing internet connectivity to several PCs. It's currently using shorewall to help make the iptables setup easier. Is there a way I can set it such that any individual host is prevented from using the entire line? I'm thinking setting the limit at 80%: So any one PC can't use more than 80% of bandwidth, thus if someone is downloading/uploading large files, the connection isn't completely overwhelmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Linux advanced routing and traffic shaping HOWTO](http://lartc.org/), which has a section bandwidth management.  It looks like the HOWTO is unmaintained, but it's still a good place to start.  The [Traffic control HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/index.html) also has good information.

Answer (score 1):

Shorewall allows limitatin per source aswell as per destination IP. For details see the official homepage http://www.shorewall.net/ConnectionRate.html